# MongoDB: Filter fields returned by aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am performing the following aggregation pipeline, over a MongoDB collection:

```
# Define an aggregation pipeline
    aggregation_pipeline = [
        {"$match": {"business_id": query["business_id"], "dt_op": query["dt_op"]}},
        {"$unwind": {"path": "$transactions"}},
    ]
```

How can I add a filtering step within the aggregation pipeline, in order to return only a selection of the document fields?

The equivalent with normal queries, using PyMongo, would be:

```
collection.find(
        # Match data
        query, 
        # Keep only columns of interest
        {
            "field_1": 1, 
            "field_2": 1, 
            "field_3": 1,
            })
```

Comment: You use aggregation `$project` stage.

Comment: It works! If you answer appropriately, I'm happy to accept it! Thank you